# ¿Cuál es el error en el siguiente código? Sleep y While en PHP

Tags: php, bucles, while

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$path_file_one = '/ruta/archivo1.txt';
$path_file_two = '/ruta/archivo2.txt';

while (is_file($path_file_one) != is_file($path_file_two)) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

La función que se busca es la siguiente:

- Salir del bucle while cuando archivo1 y archivo2 no existan o salir del bucle cuando existan los dos de forma simultánea.

Pues bien, cuando se ejecuta esta parte del código en el programa que he creado, uno de los dos archivos no existe antes de iniciar el bucle while y, si el otro archivo se borra después, el bucle while se queda colgado y sigue de forma indefinida, ¿por qué puede ser? Debería salir del bucle dado que no encuentra ninguno de los dos archivos.

He probado a iniciar el bucle sin los dos archivos, borrando sólo uno de ellos y después volviendo a crearlo o con los dos archivos creados de forma simultánea, y sólo se me queda colgado cuando pasa lo que anteriormente he mencionado.

Comment: Revisa el [*OR exclusivo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerta_XOR): `while( is_file(...) xor is_file(...) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede ser un tema de cacheo de datos por parte de PHP. Investigando en las preguntas de StackOverflow relacionadas con problemas en las funciones is_file/file_exists he encontrado [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4099146/2553194) donde se hace referencia al método **`clearstatcache`**.

Añado cita en español del [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.clearstatcache.php). He destacado en negrita la parte más relevante.

> Cuando usa stat(), lstat(), o cualquier otra función enumerada en la
> lista de funciones afectadas (abajo), PHP examina la información que
> devuelven esas funciones para proporcionar un rendimiento más rápido.
> Sin embargo, en ciertos casos, puede querer borrar la información
> almacenada en caché. Por ejemplo, si el mismo archivo está siendo
> verificado múltiples veces dentro de un sólo script, y ese archivo
> corre el peligro de ser borrado o modificado durante la operación de
> ese script, puede optar por limpiar la caché de estado. En estos
> casos, puede usar la función clearstatcache() para borrar la
> información que PHP examina del archivo.
>
> Debería observar también que PHP no examina información sobre archivos
> no existentes. Por lo que si llama a file_exists() con un archivo que
> no existe, se devolverá false a menos que cree el archivo. **Si crea el
> archivo, se devolverá true incluso si después borra el archivo**. Sin
> embargo unlink() limpia la caché automáticamente.

En la mencionada lista aparece el método `is_file`.

> Las funciones afectadas incluyen stat(), lstat(), file_exists(),
> is_writable(), is_readable(), is_executable(), **is_file()**, is_dir(),
> is_link(), filectime(), fileatime(), filemtime(), fileinode(),
> filegroup(), fileowner(), filesize(), filetype(), y fileperms().

Así que si quieres verificar que lo expuesto es cierto, solo tienes que invocar `clearstatcache` después del sleep.

```
while (is_file($path_file_one) != is_file($path_file_two)) {
    sleep(1);
    clearstatcache();
}
```